# Возможна ли конструкция "делать что-то делаться"?

Tags: словообразование

Я часто слышу от своих родственников такие выражения типа "Пойду ставить греться чайник" или "Надо включить машину стираться", и мне это всегда режет слух.

Возникает три варианта:

1. Надо говорить второй глагол без частицы СЯ
2. Надо вообще по-другому строить фразу (например, просто "Пойду поставлю чайник" или как-то ещё)
3. Они говорят правильно

Что скажут эксперты?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Сходил на кухню, **поставил греться чайник**, вспомнил о купленном вчера тортике. [Захар Прилепин. Санька (2006)].

Поставил (что?)чайник, поставил (зачем?) греться. Всё в пределах нормы, звучит естественно.

2) "Пойду ставить греться чайник".  Некорректная грамматика с двумя инфинитивами.

Надо: Пойду поставлю греться чайник. Но здесь структура усложнена неоправданно, читается плохо. Лучше так: пойду поставлю чайник.

Comment: А что Вы скажете по поводу последней фразы Сержа?

Comment: Я ее никак не найду.

Comment: "В вашем предложении нарушена не только грамматическая связь, но и глагол "греться" употреблен некорректно. В таких конструкциях два глагола должны быть употреблены в одинаковой форме: пойду напишу, пойду позову (глаголы в форме будущего времени)".

Comment: Да, всё верно, я тоже привожу похожий пример: (пойду поставлю) греться чайник, а конструкция глагол + два инфинитива некорректна. Пойду прогуляться, присел отдохнуть - здесь инфинитив не входит в сказуемое, а является обстоятельством цели.  В предложении "Пойду ставить греться чайник" совершенно неясно,   чем  является второй инфинитив, каковы его грамматические связи, поэтому оно представляется неверным.

Comment: А корректна конструкция глагол или два глагола + объект + инфинитив?

Comment: А здесь, как мне кажется, две разные связи: а) глагол управляет объектом; б) инфинитив примыкает к глаголу. Синонимичная конструкция: Я поставил чайник (на плиту), чтобы он грелся. Инфинитив заменяет придаточную часть, такая краткая форма характерна для разговорных конструкций.

Comment: Я это чувствую, что говорящий подразумевает замену придаточной части, но мне почему-то эта замена режет слух... :/

Comment: Видимо, мне неприятно, что фразу строят так сложно, то есть используют два глагола СТАВИТЬ и ГРЕТЬСЯ или даже ГРЕТЬ, касающихся чайника, вместо того, чтобы просто сказать "пойду поставлю" или "пойду подогрею" (правда, это можно сказать только про воду, поэтому основной вариант первый).

Comment: Если честно, меня и причастия немного раздражают в устной речи (как в Вашем примере "вспомнил о *купленном* вчера тортике"). Сам по возможности стараюсь их избегать.

Answer (score 1):

Вопросом - на вопрос, простите. **Хочу помочь подняться**, например,— что здесь не так? Может, в вопросе надо что-то подправить? Если не о типе конструкций размышлять, а именно об этих (см. вопрос) выражениях, то корректно было бы, сохраняя основные глаголы, говорить: **Ставить греться воду** и **Положить бельё стираться**. При всеобщем увлечении коротко выражаться, фразы выглядят архаично. Варианты короче: **Поставлю чайник** и **Надо постирать**

Comment: Помочь подняться - два глагола стоят в одинаковой форме.

Comment: "Пойду ставить греться чайник" или "Надо включить машину стираться", и мне это всегда режет слух, — это сейчас предмет вопроса «Как по-другому строить фразу».

Comment: Так измените свой Вопрос, Artyom Lugovoy! Внесу и я изменения для комплекта: вместо «Помочь подняться» — «Хочу помочь подняться».

Comment: Я уж было совсем запутался. Теперь дошло. :)

Comment: Только "помочь подняться" или "хочу помочь подняться" - это одно и то же в смысле, что глаголы стоят друг за другом без объекта.

Comment: Хочу помочь шарику подняться.

Answer (score 0):

А мне кажется, здесь всё нормально. Чайник же может ***греться***. Чайник ***нагревается***. Постфикс *ся* имеет множество значений, и здесь мы не можем отмазаться простым утверждением «греет себя». Надо к грамматике (а точнее, к морфологии) обращаться, чтобы точно узнать, возможна ли такая конструкция.

Answer (score 0):

Многое зависит от того, возможен ли процесс без участия говорящего. С чайником такое возможно: условно говоря, он "**греет себя**" сам - я его поставил на огонь или включил, и он будто сам **греется**. В примере со стиральной машиной ошибка в том, что машина в таком процессе не "стирает себя". Зато можно **оставить** машину "**крутиться**", а **бельё** в ней - "**стираться**". При этом можно на время отойти: всё будет "**делаться**" само, автоматически. При этом можно в равной мере трактовать такие процессы как "чайник греется огнём" или он "греется сам собой".

Comment: Бабы стирались на реке до вечера. Стирались может использоваться в значении стирали. Но применительно к машинке это не звучит. Машинка стиралась до вечера.

Comment: "Бабы стирались" - явное _просторечие_; из современных равноценных вариантов: сотрудник, отправившийся к удаленному ксероксу, говорит начальнику, что "пошел размножаться".

Answer (score 0):

В данном случае здесь простое осложненное глагольное сказуемое, выраженное  двумя глаголами в разной форме. Однако в русском языке для обозначения  действия и его цели должны употребляться в одинаковой форме. В вашем предложении нарушена не только грамматическая связь, но и глагол "греться". употреблен некорректно. В таких конструкциях два глагола должны быть употреблены в одинаковой форме: пойду напишу, пойду позову ( глаголы в форме будущего времени).

Comment: Вот! И я постоянно для себя пытался аргументировать как-то внутреннее ощущение, что они должны быть в одной форме. По крайней мере, когда первый глагол подразумевает активное действие,  возвратный второй воспринимается очень странно.